# Ship in access plan has very high cost

Tags: sql, db2, sql-execution-plan, sqlperformance

I got this query:

```
select 
    count(1) as total 
from 
    Document 
join 
    ClaimDocument on ClaimDocument.documentId = Document.documentId 
where 
    (Document.latestChangeLogonUserId = 1) and 
    (Document.documentStatusId = 1)
```

Which executes the following access plan:

```
Total Cost:         8.45269e+07
Query Degree:       1

           Rows 
          RETURN
          (   1)
           Cost 
            I/O 
            |
             1 
          GRPBY 
          (   2)
        8.45269e+07 
        2.16185e+07 
            |
          2090.31 
          MSJOIN
          (   3)
        8.45269e+07 
        2.16185e+07 
      /-----+------\
  25971.7         0.080484 
  TBSCAN           FILTER
  (   4)           (   7)
8.45092e+07        17717.3 
2.1589e+07         29952.7 
    |                |
  25971.7        5.39219e+06 
  SORT             IXSCAN
  (   5)           (   8)
8.45092e+07        17717.3 
2.1589e+07         29952.7 
    |                |
  25971.7        5.39219e+06 
  SHIP         INDEX: CD     
  (   6)     ClDoc_docuId_claiId
8.45092e+07          Q2
2.1589e+07 
    |
8.63559e+07 
NICKNM: CD     
 DOCUMENT
    Q1
```

Notice the tremendous costs of the ship. I can't find any information on the internet how to improve the speed of a ship query.

Document and ClaimDocument are in 2 seperated databases. I have ofcourse some indexes, but they do not increase the speed. In the access plan I got the following information about the ship:

```
6) SHIP  : (Ship)
    Cumulative Total Cost:      8.45092e+07
    Cumulative CPU Cost:        3.58355e+11
    Cumulative I/O Cost:        2.1589e+07
    Cumulative Re-Total Cost:   26574.5
    Cumulative Re-CPU Cost:     2.25043e+11
    Cumulative Re-I/O Cost:     0
    Cumulative First Row Cost:  3277.92
    Estimated Bufferpool Buffers:   2.1589e+07
    Remote Total Cost:  13426.5
    Remote Communication Cost:  13422.5

    Arguments:
    ---------
    CSERQY  : (Remote common subexpression)
        FALSE
    DSTSEVER: (Destination (ship to) server)
        - (NULL).
    RMTQTXT : (Remote statement)
        SELECT A0."DOCUMENTID" C0 FROM "CD"."DOCUMENT" A0 WHERE (A0."LATESTCHANGELOGONUSERID" = 24926) AND (A0."DOCUMENTSTATUSID" = -1) FOR READ ONLY
    SRCSEVER: (Source (ship from) server)
        CDDOC
    STREAM  : (Remote stream)
        FALSE

    Predicates:
    ----------
    3) Sargable Predicate, 
        Comparison Operator:        Equal (=)
        Subquery Input Required:    No
        Filter Factor:          0.2

        Predicate Text:
        --------------
        (Q1.DOCUMENTSTATUSID = 1)


    4) Sargable Predicate, 
        Comparison Operator:        Equal (=)
        Subquery Input Required:    No
        Filter Factor:          0.00150376

        Predicate Text:
        --------------
        (Q1.LATESTCHANGELOGONUSERID = 1)



    Input Streams:
    -------------
        1) From Object CD.DOCUMENT

            Estimated number of rows:   8.63559e+07
            Number of columns:      4
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q1.$RID$+Q1.DOCUMENTSTATUSID
            +Q1.LATESTCHANGELOGONUSERID+Q1.DOCUMENTID


    Output Streams:
    --------------
        2) To Operator #5

            Estimated number of rows:   25971.7
            Number of columns:      1
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q1.DOCUMENTID
```

Has anyone experience with shipping statements and how to improve the speed?

Comment: "Tables are in two separated databases" , please be specific do you mean one is a nickname (using federation). If so, are the two databases using the same RDBMS? Has NNSTAT been run recently? If using federation, what server-options are configured, in particular the predicate-pushdowns

Comment: [Explain operators](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.explain.doc/doc/r0052023.html)

Comment: It's bringing the whole remote table `DOCUMENT` (operator #6), and then it applies the filtering (operator #3). I don't see how to improve it; it's the remote data fetching that has the potential of being colossal. Actually, can you run the query from the other database instead? The filtering would be done locally (much faster).